# Is there a way to iterate through a list of lists without getting an index error?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a list of lists and I am trying to pull out every nth term from each list within the list.

Here is my input:

```
[['', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2035', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 
'', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '2', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2036', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'1TD1131D17025-2037', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', 
'\n']]
```

Right now I am trying to pull out the first integer from each list.

Here is my sample code.

```
def find(n,e):
    for line in range(len(line_nu)):
        item = line_nu[n][e]
        n += 1
    return item_nu.append(item)
```

I'm getting an 'Index out of range' error.
I can call ' line_nu[0][4] ' outside of this loop, but using same numbers in def find() I get an error. I have also tried this as a while loop where I replace n with i and start count at 0. Same error.
End goal is to get each none '' in a list of its own.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks very confused. Why are you looping if you just want to jump to a certain element anyway? You are not using `line` at all in the loop. Why does your function return the result of `list.append`, which is `None`? Why are you appending to `line_nu`? There is so much fundamentally wrong with this that you should restart from scratch, and first learn how lists and loops work, what functions are, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted your question as looking for the nth non-empty element in each sub list, so elements != ''. This function will execute that and return an array of the nth non-empty element in each sub array

```
exl = [['', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2035', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 
'', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '2', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2036', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'1TD1131D17025-2037', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', 
'\n']]

def find(n,listOfLists):
    result = []
    for list in listOfLists:
        discoveredItems = 0
        for item in list:
            if item != '':
                discoveredItems += 1
                if discoveredItems == n:
                    result.append(item)
                    break
    return result
```

So to get the first non-empty item in each list (the integers you mentioned above)...

```
find(1,exl)
# ['1', '2', '3']
```

And the dates (aka 3rd non-empty element):

```
find(3,exl)
# ['09/16/2022', '09/16/2022', '09/16/2022']
```

Comment: I'm sure there are more pythonic/cleaner way, but love how you pretty much indexed the item being pulled so I do not have to know the exact position of the element in the list. Went through 9k lines perfectly only 3 lines had slightly different positions. An easy fix though. Thank you.

Comment: @McClain you're right there are more succinct ways to do this, but hopefully this answer will give some people a better idea of the logic or the structure they can edit for their unique purposes. I hope my code helped, I've used it similarly for converting to pandas dataframes

Comment: Next step is to DATAFRAME for me too. Just have to remember the deeper I go into Inception the more "for" loops I'll need to pull something out.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, if you know how many columns you have, you could just do a single for loop: ```for i in range(1,nCols): df.insert(loc=0,column=str(i),value=find(i,exl))```

Answer (score 2):

assuming your list of lists has the name `data`, we can get the first integer of each sublist like:

```
data = [[...],[...],...]
for list in data:
    for item in list:
        if item.isdigit():
            print(item)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two `for` loops.  For example:

```
test = [['', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2035', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 
'', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '2', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2036', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'1TD1131D17025-2037', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', 
'\n']

for row in range(len(test)):
    for col in range(len(test[row])):
        print(test[row][col])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are always at the same index for all sublists, you can get a list of the numbers (as strings) by looping once:

```
def find(lists, n):
    out = []
    for lst in lists:
        out.append(lst[n])
    return out

# call it with n=4
numbers = find(mylists, 4)
```

Obviously, a list comprehension can more appropriate here

```
def find(lists, n):
    return [lst[n] for lst in lists]
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I still got an index error using it. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [['', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2035', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 
'', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '2', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '1TD1131D17025-2036', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '09/16/2022', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'353.60', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '707.20', '\n'], ['', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'1TD1131D17025-2037', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '09/16/2022', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', 'EA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '353.60', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '707.20', 
'\n']]
for _ in range(len(L)):
    print(set(L[_]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'', '707.20', '353.60', '1TD1131D17025-2035', '2', 'EA', '09/16/2022', '1', '\n'}
{'', '707.20', '353.60', '2', 'EA', '09/16/2022', '1TD1131D17025-2036', '\n'}
{'', '707.20', '353.60', '2', 'EA', '09/16/2022', '1TD1131D17025-2037', '\n', '3'}
```